# Dojo 1.7.2 several files Flash uploader for IE with form data = One POST for each file submitted?

Tags: flash, file-upload, plugins, dojo

Hi All and first of all thanks a lot for reading me !
I'm using Dojo 1.7.2 with Domino 8.5 server to submit form data with several user selected files to a database.

I'm using `dojox.form.Uploader` with Flash plugin (multiple file selection enabled) in a IE (7 and 8) only environment.
(iFrame plugin does not work with our IE due to an "Access denied" error)

Everything works great with one file but as soon as the user wants to upload more than one file, the POST is submitted as many times as there are files.

For example, if the user wants to send his data + 3 selected files, after he has clicked once on my 'submit' button, Domino server will receive 3 POSTs (each containing one file and the form data) resulting in 3 incomplete records : all form data are present in each record with only one of the 3 files :
Record 1 : same Form Data & File 1
Record 2 : same Form Data & File 2
Record 3 : same Form Data & File 3

I want to receive 1 POST with : form Data & 3 files

I don't know if this is the way it is supposed to work (couldn't find any detailed info on 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/form/Uploader.html#id7 nor on http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/uploader/) or if I've set it up the wrong way.

Any help very appreciated !

Additional info : HTML file upload names for Domino are very specific and contain `%` and `$` (e.g.:`%%File.c1257b1a0053689e.fdbe327b47e4b280c1257b35005b38e5.$Body.0.33B4`) so I had to `encodeURIComponent` them. For testing purpose, I successfully made it work with  iFrame plugin on Firefox by just switching from `'flash'` plugin to '`iframe`'.

```
// Dijit form containing dojox.form.Uploader
this._oForm = new dijit.form.Form({ 
    name: "_mMsg",  
    method: "POST",  
    action: "/mMsg?CreateDocument",  
    encType: 'multipart/form-data',  
    onSubmit: function(){  
    return true;  
}, "idForm_" + sMsgId);  

this._oFileUploader = new dojox.form.Uploader({  
    id: "idFileUploader_" + sMsgId,  
    label: "Add files",  
    iconClass: "ButtonAttachFile",  
    multiple: true,  
    force: 'flash',  
    swfPath: dojo.baseUrl + '../dojox/form/resources/uploader.swf?Open',  
    serverTimeout: 180000,  
    isDebug: true,  
    devMode: true,  
    deferredUploading: 10, //Max # files uploaded simultaneously  
    fieldname: encodeURIComponent(sFileUploadControlName),  
    name: encodeURIComponent(sFileUploadControlName),  
    flashFieldName: encodeURIComponent(sFileUploadControlName),  
    "class": "FileUploader",  
    onComplete: dojo.hitch(this, '_onCompleteUploadFlash'),  
    onError: dojo.hitch(this, '_onErrorUploadFlash')  
});  

var oForm = {  
    Form: "mFile",  
    MsgId: sMsgId,  
    MsgDbKey: sMsgDbKey  
    Body:sBody,  
    Subject:sSubject  
};  
this._oFileUploader.upload(oForm);
```

Thanks a lot in advance !